# Setting null objects for GC vs WeakReference in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Iam a little bit confused about what does WeakReference actually do. From what i've read let me explain:

Example1:

```
Integer prime = 1;  
WeakReference<Integer> soft = new WeakReference<Integer>(prime); 
prime = null;
```

In the next gc cycle prime will be collected. So far so good. But if i do this without WeakReference:

```
Integer prime = 1;  
prime = null;
```

Isn't the same thing? Prime will be collected again because there is no reference.

Comment: Even setting to `null` is unnecessary, as `prime` will probably fall out of scope and be eligible for GC. Does this mean `WeakReference` is useless? No, it just means your example is very poor. I recommend searching existing questions on `WeakReference`, but you probably shouldn't worry too much about it. It's a very specialized class, not something you use regularly. Also if you're explicitly setting references to `null` as if by default, that's a bad and useless habit.

Comment: In your first example you could however write `soft.get()` in the next line while you could not do that in your second example. I mean the whole idea of a WeakReference is not to enable garbage collection but to have a weak reference to an object that will be GCed when there is no strong reference to it anymore. There are use cases where a WeakReference is what you want.

Comment: @Kayaman why didn't you write it as an answer?

Comment: @Imaskar I should've looked for a dupe instead.

Comment: @Kayaman What do you mean by "will probably fall out of scope"?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136620/weak-references-how-useful-are-they

Comment: Well a variable falling out of scope (or rather the object it's referring to) will be eligible for GC whether you've assigned `null` to it or not. As short lived objects are very common compared to long lived objects, you rarely see explicit nulling of variables. Not that it matters, the example itself is flawed.

Comment: @Kayaman even falling out of scope is not necessary if the object is otherwise unused. See [finalize() called on strongly reachable object in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642153/finalize-called-on-strongly-reachable-object-in-java-8)…

Comment: @Holger interesting, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is not a particularly good one. It's certainly not a valid [use-case for a `WeakReference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790511/is-there-a-practical-use-for-weak-references). For starters, the `Integer` 1 will always be present in [the `Integer` cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java), so will always have a strong reference to it.

A `WeakReference` will hold a reference to an object as long as something else holds a (strong) reference to it. Imagine a particularly [fickle person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheep). They will like a TV show/song/movie ... but only if someone else likes it. Once everyone else stops liking that thing, they will promptly lose interest as well.

---

Also, be careful here:

```
WeakReference<Integer> soft
```

`WeakReference` and `SoftReference` are [closely related but are not interchangeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299659/whats-the-difference-between-softreference-and-weakreference-in-java).

Comment: Is it useless to setting variables to null? If that so, how else do we declare that we want an object to be garbage collected?

Comment: Local variables? Yes, most of the time it's useless. They will shortly go [out of scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ops/scope.html) and will be eligible for garbage collection anyway. Fields of classes are a slightly different matter. Sometimes there are valid reasons to make those null.

Comment: @Michael for optimized code, it is not even necessary that local variables go out of scope. All that matters, is, whether the object is subsequently used. For non-optimized executions, references may sometimes hanging in a stack frame, even if the variable is out of scope. Usually, it doesn’t matter. Only in very rare corner cases, setting a variable to `null` may have a point (which would require understanding of the underlying byte code and a particular JVM’s garbage collection algorithm).